# Default text in an input field

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

I looked for this everywhere but I couldn't find anything useful.
I need a way to put a default text (preferably a php variable) in a HTML text field whenever I load the page. It's like a placeholder (I'm aware of the placeholder attribute, I don't want that) that doesn't disappear so that the user can submit that value if he wants.

I'm guessing it can be done with a simple javascript script but I suck at that.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the value attribute then: value="text here"

With a PHP variable, it would be something like this:

```
<form action="path-here">
  <input type="text" name="field-name" value="<?php echo $variable; ?>"><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways to put a default value in a text field.

The first way is the simplest. All it involves is setting the value of the text field.

```
<input type="text" id="myTextBox" value="Some default text">
```

The second was uses a JavaScript function that runs when the page loads.

```
<!-- This solution is a little more complicated. -->
<body onload="setDefaultText()"> 
   ...
   <input type="text" id="myTextBox">
</body>
<script>
  function setDefaultText() {
     document.getElementById("myTextBox").value = "Some default text";
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wjt8foh1/)** Example

```
<form>
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname" value="John"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" value="Doe"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit form">
</form>
```

You are looking for the value="Text Here"